# How to "create" a bigger height difference between the continents and oceans of this Earth model?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, normal-map, height-map, bump

[image: Node Setups and visual]

I assume missing something very basic, but I can't for the life of me figure out a way to properly increase the "height" of the continents . Still sort of new in using Blender and I feel like I should be able to solve this relatively easily. Tried using a different image as a normal map, adding different nodes in the shader setup, adding a SubD modifier.[image: example]The example above is similar to what I'd like to possibly achieve.

Comment: to achieve a believable effect you'll have to use adaptive subdivision (under experimental features), the cycles render engine and true displacement (not normal map). You can achieve the result with eevee but you'll have to duplicate your sphere a bunch of time to create the illusion of volume. Both solutions are extremely computationally heavy. Another solution is to use geometry nodes and a heavily subdivided sphere (not UV sphere or you'll have pinching artifacts at the poles)

Comment: you can either create real displacement or fake displacement (with a bump or a normal map), what you show in your second picture is real displacement. You can have a good result with fake displacement but you need a b&w map that is slightly blurred to get a good result imho